# Scraping web articles and export them in to a pandas DataFrame - Issue with null objects

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape news articles and export them into a pandas data frame. However, before that I tried to put them into different lists; but the lists are in different sizes. So, how can I append the null value if the object does not exist? I tried the following: but it dose not work.

```
def news_scraping_wienerzeitung():
   wienerzeitung_url='https://www.wienerzeitung.at/'
   html = requests.get(wienerzeitung_url)
   bsobj_3 = soup(html.content, 'html.parser')

   links = []
   for link in bsobj_3.find_all('a', attrs={'href': 
   re.compile("^https://www.wienerzeitung.at/nachrichten")}):
   link = link['href']
   links.append(link)

   lst1 = []
   lst2 = []
  lst3 = []
  lst4 = []


 for l in links:
     page = requests.get(l)
     b = soup(page.content)

     for m in b.findAll('h1',{'class' : 'article-title d-inline'}):
        lst1.append(m.text.strip())

     lstA =[]
     for data in b.find_all("p", {'id' :'absatz1'}): 
        lstA.append(data.get_text())
      q = ' '.join(lstA)
      lst2.append(q)

     for k in b.findAll('span',{'class' : 'article-published'}):
       lst3.append(k.text.strip())

     for p in b.findAll('link',{'rel' : 'amphtml'}):
        r = p['href']
       if p:
          lst4.append(r)
       else:
          lst4.append('null')

  lst2 = list(filter(None, lst2))
  print(len(lst3))
  print(len(lst1))
  print(len(lst2))
  print(len(lst4))


Following is the output

113
113
113
109`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
if x in article:
    append(x)
else:
    append('no data')
```